# Prove or disprove that $x+y+z+t\geq 85$ for $\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{y^2}=\dfrac{1}{z^2}-\dfrac{1}{t^2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,z,t$ be distinct positive integers satisfy
 $\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{y^2}=\dfrac{1}{z^2}-\dfrac{1}{t^2}$

What is the minimum value of $x+y+z+t$ ?

I found that $\dfrac{1}{56^2}-\dfrac{1}{14^2}=\dfrac{1}{8^2}-\dfrac{1}{7^2}$ $\rightarrow$ $x+y+z+t=85$.

Is this the minimum value ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: This can easily be solved by a computer program.

Comment: Can it be solve by manual?

Comment: for $x=y=z=t=1$ we get $4$ as the searched minimum

Comment: x,y,z,t are distinct

Comment: @quester The four numbers are positive *integers*.

Comment: @VTand true, thanks for remark

Comment: A computer search shows that $85$ is indeed the minimum value.